# Deep learning in partially defined parameter space

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression

I have a deep learning problem, which I intend to solve in Keras with CNN. The task is 1D regression, for which I generate grayscale images using 2 parameters and the parameter to be deduced by the network (this is temperature difference). The image generation has 3 parameters, everything else is random. Naturally, the image generation occurs only in a region of each of the parameters. Of course the images visually represent the temperature difference.

The network has 2 inputs: two scalars as a vector (the 2 additional parameters for image generation) and the image. The aim of the teaching is to deduce the temperature difference from the supplied image.

My problem is the image generation is not always possible because of geometric constraints. There is a subregion of the 3 parameters used for generation, where it will fail. The red circles represent this in the figure below. Two axes of the figure is logarithmic, but as seen from the sample distribution, the parameter pick uses exponential-like distribution.

Learning proves to be quite good on the lower left region of the parameters, but totally unusable on the other end.

My question is if the poor model performance can be a result of the shape of the taught parameters, especially the failed region?

I forgot to mention that the images used are 256*256 8-bit grayscale. Training code:

```
def createMlp(aRepeatParameter:int):
  vectorSize = aRepeatParameter * 2
  inputs = Input(shape=(vectorSize,))
  x = inputs
  return Model(inputs, x)

def createCnn():
  filters=(64, 16, 4)
  inputShape = (256, 256, 1)
  chanDim = -1
  inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
  x = inputs
  for (i, f) in enumerate(filters):
    x = Conv2D(f, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(128, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))(x)
  x = Dense(16, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Dense(4)(x)
  x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
  return Model(inputs, x)

repeatParameter:int = 2
mlp = createMlp(repeatParameter)
cnn = createCnn()

combinedInput = Concatenate(axis=1)([mlp.output, cnn.output])
x = Dense(4, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))(combinedInput)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs=[mlp.input, cnn.input], outputs=x)

batchSize = 32
sampleSize = 96000
validationSize = 16000
port      = 12345
trainingSteps = math.ceil(sampleSize / batchSize)
learningRate = ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=trainingSteps, decay_rate=0.05)
opt = Adam(learning_rate=learningRate)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=opt, metrics=["mean_absolute_percentage_error"])
model.fit(landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter, port), validation_data=landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter, port),
  epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=trainingSteps, validation_steps=validationSize/batchSize )
```

[image: Parameter distribution. Blue: image generation succeeds, red: fails.]

Comment: There are many possible reasons for poor model performance. Not normalizing the input data, overfitting or underfitting, issues with the model architecture. Please show some reproducible code

Comment: I add the actual model in the question.
[Here](https://gitlab.wigner.hu/bamer.balazs/numerical-simulate-mirage/-/tree/development) is the full code. For learning, one must run `./Pybind11AiTrainerImageServer --threads 16 &; python3 trainAiTemp.py` and inference is done by `./TestInference.sh trainAiTemp.model [distance in meters] [desired temperature difference between 0 and 5]`